# Android gradle - build according to market

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using android-studio 0.5.9 with gradle. I want to make build for each market so I've decided to create some buildTypes like this

`buildTypes {
        englishAlpha {
            runProguard false
            packageNameSuffix '.alpha.en'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEV'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            zipAlign true
        }
        germanAlpha {
            runProguard false
            packageNameSuffix '.alpha.de'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEV'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            zipAlign true
        }
        englishBeta {
            runProguard false
            packageNameSuffix '.beta.en'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        germanBeta {
            runProguard false
            packageNameSuffix '.beta.de'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }`

The problem is when I want to update drawables (each market has its own drawables), I have to update two directories (alpha & beta) for now and three later (release) for one market.

Is there a way for having all drawables in two directories (EN and DE) for all buildVariant ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use product flavor in combination with buildTypes to create buildVariant. The buildVariants will be the cartesian product : buildType X productFlavor

In your case, create 2 product flavor : `alpha` and `beta` and 2 build types : `german` and `english`

packageNameSuffix is only allowed in buildType.
You can use packageName in flavor, so your build.gradle must look like this :

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        alpha {
            packageName 'com.company.alpha'
        }

        beta {
            packageName 'com.company.beta'
        }
    } 
    buildTypes {
        english {
            packageNameSuffix '.en'
        }

        german {
            packageNameSuffix '.de'
        }
    }
 }
```

If you place your drawables:

- for english buildtype in `src/english/res/drawable-*/`
- for german buildtype in `src/german/res/drawable-*/`
- and the common ones in `src/main/res/drawable-*/`

This will give you 4 build variants with 2 distinct sets of drawables (one for english and one for german)

Comment: Ok but if I have custom drawable for english alpha and german alpha (for example launcher), what is the path ?

Comment: @aat src/alphaEnglish/res/drawable-*/ and src/alphaGerman/res/drawable-*/ must be good

Comment: like this, I can't add versionNameSuffix for alpha build anymore ?